# Regulating a LiMnO2 battery at 3V

Tags: voltage, led, batteries, voltage-regulator

I need your knowledge and experience for a problem I am having.

I am designing an embedded system which is powered by a 3V LiMnO2 battery. The battery operates at 3V and this covers all needs.

Except for a green LED which is best operated at 3-3.3V. As long as the battery is healthy enough, the LED works fine, but overtime and with steeper voltage drops (to 2.85 and such) the brightness of the LED deteriorates and damages the signal.

Do you think using a regulator is needed in this circuit? Or regulating a 3V circuit powered  by a 3V battery for voltage drops of 0.1 is not a good idea?

It is very important for us that the device can work for a very long time (2 years), so the power consumption of the regulator is also very important.

Is it generally worth it? What are my options?

Comment: What does the LED indicate?

Comment: @pipe Generating light so that the reflection is read by a photodiode, the weaker the LED, the weaker the signal

Comment: @Sina was my answer any use to you then?

Comment: Why a green LED? An infra red would often work better in this sort of application and could run off half the voltage.

Comment: @Finbarr unfortunately infrared is not an option right now, but I will look into other colours than red, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you have 2 options here. You can either find a new LED with a lower Vf or you can get a boost regulator to bring your voltage up to a 5V rail. There are quite a few low power ones out there, and if you want to save more power you can toggle an enable pin on and off on most devices.

This constant 5V (or whatever you decide you want it as) will ensure your LED does not dim. Even when your battery drops, most of these low power devices will keep a constant output with very low input voltages, which means it should stay stable all the way through the lifetime of your battery. And if your design is space critical, there are some small package ICs out there with fast switching which should enable you to keep your external components small too.

TI or Maxim do some decent low power chips that should suit your needs.

Just make sure you look at the efficiency graphs on the datasheets!

**EDIT** As pointed out by Dampmaskin, there is of course a third option, which is to use a different battery. A Li-Ion battery as he mentioned has a nominal cell voltage of 3.6V which should suit your needs too.

Comment: Third option, use a battery with a higher voltage, like for instance Li-ion.

Comment: Ha! I can't believe I forgot something like that! Very good point, I shall add it into my answer after slapping my forehead and yelling 'DOH'

Comment: A Li-ion would be rechargeable though, whereas LiMnO2 is disposable.

Comment: @Finbarr very true, suppose it depends on his requirements and design!

Comment: @MCG Thanks for the detailed answer. Changing the LED seems to be easier at the moment, if not I will look into boost regulators of course. Would have loved to hear your recommendation for such ICs, but I guess part recommendation is not allowed here (tell me some general point to pay attention to though, I would very much appreciate it)

Comment: @Dampmaskin  That is also an option, but the device should run for a long time without the need of charging and as far as I know, LiMnO2 has the highest mAh of all for what we need, please correct me if I am wrong